# find: ‘/e’: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, cygwin, zsh

I all of the sudden started getting this message at startup in my command line.

> find: ‘/e’: No such file or directory

I have no idea what '/e' is and what's causing this to happen. Does anyone know what this is? If not, is there a way to get more information on this message I'm getting? I'm new to Zsh, Cygwin, and Oh My Zsh so I don't really know what to do, or what's causing it.

I would really appreciate anyone's help. This is driving me crazy. I seem to still be able to do everything, but I get this every time I start 'babun'.

Oh by the way, I'm using babun, which is a convenient way of getting Cygwin, Zsh, Oh My Zsh, Git, etc. Here's the link of that. I doubt babun itself has anything to do with this though. 
http://babun.github.io/

Comment: Please do not edit the answer into the question. You can either post it as an actual answer to your own question and accept it, especially if you feel that someone else may profit from it. Or you can just delete the question. If you edit the answer into the question, it still looks like an unanswered question from the outside, so others with similar questions will not look for an answer here. And people willing to help will open and read it for nothing because you are not actually looking for an answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! So '/e' is my flash drive that I had disconnected. All I had to do was delete the 'e' file in the cygwin directory and it was resolved. There are also files named 'c' and 'd' for other drives.